# How to pass request for a delete method in junit

Tags: junit, http-delete

Hi I have a json request which I have to pass in my junit testcase but the request is delete as delete do not support setEntity method. How can I pass the request in my testcase. 
Json request which I have to pass

{

```
"userId":"AJudd",
"siteId":"131",
"alternateSiteId":"186"
```

}

mytest case for this

```
@Test
    public void testdeleteAltSite() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        String resultCode = "001";
        String resultText = "Success";
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/adminrest1/alternatesite";
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpDelete delete = new HttpDelete(url);

        // add header
        delete.addHeader("Transaction-Id", "11");
        delete.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        LOG.info(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(delete);

        byte[] buf = new byte[512];
        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        int count = 0;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(1024);
        while ((count = is.read(buf, 0, 512)) > 0) {
            builder.append(new String(buf, 0, count));
        }
        String output = builder.toString();
        System.out.println(output);

    }`
```

How to pass the json value so that the passed value data can be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all: Sending a body with a DELETE is not what usually happens around the internet. Nevertheless, it is not forbidden ([Is an entity body allowed for an HTTP DELETE request?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/299628/7489452)). So, two ideas:

**1) New class**

I assume you use org.apache.http.client: Just extend `HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase`:

```
public class HttpDeleteWithEntity extends HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase {

    public final static String METHOD_NAME = "DELETE";

    public HttpDeleteWithEntity() {
        super();
    }

    public HttpDeleteWithEntity(final URI uri) {
        super();
        setURI(uri);
    }

    public HttpDeleteWithEntity(final String uri) {
        super();
        setURI(URI.create(uri));
    }

    @Override
    public String getMethod() {
        return METHOD_NAME;
    }

}
```

This is basically c&p'ed from the `HttpPost` class. I did not test this, tho.

Then use your `HttpDeleteWithEntity` class instead of `HttpDelete`.

**2) Use custom headers**

If you can modify your server code that might be a good alternative.

```
delete.addHeader("testwith", jsonString);
```

or

```
delete.addHeader("userId","AJudd");
delete.addHeader("siteId","131");
delete.addHeader("alternateSiteId","186);
```

*Finally*, if you are in charge of the server implementation I would recommend to implement DELETE requests without any body (see artemisian's answer).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is a problem with your design.

If your intent is to delete an alternate site and its id is unique then passing the alternateSiteId as part of the  URI should sufficient:

```
Method: DELETE
URL: http://localhost:8080/adminrest1/alternatesite/{alternateSiteId}
```

If alternateSiteId is not unique then you are updating a relationship. In that case you should use a PUT which allows you to include a body in your request. Please note you should pass the id of the resource you are updating as part of your URI, for example:

```
Method: PUT
URL: http://localhost:8080/adminrest1/alternatesite/{userId}
Body:{ 
       "siteId":"131",
       "alternateSiteId":"186"
}
```